# run an agent it failed,what and how to work on this issue?

Tags: obiee

agent didn't deliver the analysis or report successfully,what and how to work on this issue? please help me out 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The answer is always: Look at the log files. They contain all the information. You can't solve any issues without looking at the log files.